# Creating a query with mongoDB and mgo

Tags: mongodb, mgo

I have a collection of mongoDB entries like the one below...

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4e2a4ca7f21a81331f0006c3"),
  "users": {
    "bob": 1375496448, "alice": 1375496448
  },
  ...other values...
}
```

I am looking for a simple query for me to find all entries...
1) Without user `x` in users
2) With user `x` in users where the corresponding value is < `y`

I hope this question is not too trivial, but I just started learning mongoDB this afternoon and I would like to get it up and running in a simple server I am planning to set up. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide more info on the collection. It's hard to query the collection without a better idea of the collections structure. Cheers

Comment: The struct I am using for this collection is
    Address string,  
    Port string,  
    Timestamp int,  
    Users map[string]int  

I need to have a query to return the union of the 2 cases listed above. I hope this helps! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your collection is named users.

1)db.users.find({'users.X':{$exists:false}})

2)db.users.find({'users.X':{$lt:y}})

Comment: Is there anyway to take the UNION of both results? How would I structure that in mgo syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Ishaan's answer should work for you. I am only adding a way to Union the two queries.

```
db.users.find( {$or: [ {'users.X':{$exists:false}}, {'users.X':{$lt:y}} ] } )
```

You will find documentation of operators like $or, $and, etc. on this [page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/).